# Web server for a static site on Ubuntu Minimal server 14.04. What to choose?

Tags: webserver

I have a VPS working on a Ubuntu 14.04 Minimal Server and I need to install a web server for a static web-site on this VPS, no database, no scripts background and minimal traffic. As far a I can see there are few different web server implementations.

What are the differences between them and how do I decide which is best for me. My site is totally static.

Comment: Disregarding any pro or cons: I would still stick with apache. The documentation and faqs on apache on the web are great and abundantly available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) (version 1.4.6 for Ubuntu 14.04), an event driven - asynchronous server.

- Installation:

  `sudo apt-get update`

  `sudo apt-get install nginx`

Visit 127.0.0.1 to see the default page

- Start/stop the service

  `sudo service nginx stop`

  `sudo service nginx start`

  `sudo service nginx restart`

The server comes with the default site configuration which you can base yours.